# adding initial velocity to rigid body with cell fracture

Tags: physics

I have a raindrop (active rigid) object that falls and hits a rock (passive) object, and splinters into 10 pieces ( using cell fracture add-on).

1. I made one rigid body ( passive ) and one rigid body (active) breaking into 10 pieces upon impact with passive object.

Problem:
I want an initial velocity pretty high.

Possible solution:
I was able to successfully make a solid (non-splintering) test rigid body object speed up with this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGIbSlbOpE4&ab_channel=EngMorph

But when I tried exactly the same method (keyframing at 2 frames, the location and toggling on and off Animated at Frame 1 and 3) with the cell fracture object, it does not work. It just starts at zero speed.

Comment: @Chris I understand that ingratitude is indeed a great sin, and I do not blame your distaste in helping someone whom you have concluded is ungrateful based on a limited information about the person over the Internet. Contrary to what you think, I am grateful for every user's helpful input, but I do apologize for my minimal level of interaction on my question posts which so offended you and probably others. I appreciate your feedback here. I have taken it, and will be interacting with other users more.

Comment: pls give us a bit more information or provide your blend file. We need to know when you set what values to your keyframes. So when did you set the location keyframes (at what keyframes) and when did you set the animated flag?

Comment: Sam I'm on an older version here and can't load your file, consequently I'm still somewhat confused as to exactly what it is you're trying to achieve.  Is it that you not only want the striking object to have plenty of velocity, but also to deform on contact?  Or is the cell fracture object you want  deformed on contact?  i.e. just before it shatters?

Comment: Deforming on contact (breaking into pieces) should be taken care of by the cell fracture tool.  What I wanted is the starting velocity of the entire object, which doesn't work with the the way the tutorial link showed it. But the closest workaround is the Rigid Body World Gravity under Scene Properties, I found.

Comment: So at the collision frame you want the cell fractured object to be propelled some distance as a whole before breaking up, or is it the broken segments that haven't got enough initial velocity on impact? I use cell-fracture often and your problem (and how to tackle it) is of some interest.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

after i downloaded your file, there were some strange things going on, i cannot explain why these things happen, but on my machine in my Blender version i could make it work this way:

1. turn off rigid body world (if i didn't do this, i couldn't even set location breakpoints the way i wanted because it jumped back always - although i cleared the cached rigid body world)
2. set keyframes for location + animated as you know it
3. turn on rigid body body world  -> now your described thing happens: the speed won't taken into account
4. change shape to mesh and it will work

[image]

[image]

---

here is how it should work:

keyframe animated, keyframe location (at same frame), keyframe location at later frame + animated, keyframe animated off at frame + 1

[image]

Comment: This is my blend file, with the rigid body(passive) object, and the rigid body(active object) with Cell Fracture effect to it, which shatters into 10 pieces upon contact with the passive object. Thank you for taking a look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G1aXiY5A8G6DrCZE4TFa_Y6qYgCRCXPg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That method seems only to work with an object which does not deform with Cell fracture. I have tested with a regular rigid body with Animated toggle in subsequent frames to give it initial speed, and it works fine. But not with cell fracture objects, which simply starts again at zero acceleration. The closest work around I found is to crank up the Rigid Body World Gravity under Scene Properties.

Comment: i updated my answer. i cannot retract my downvote of your question because Blender SE won't let me until you make an edit to your question. This is just one of many silly rules Blender SE has. Sometimes i think the guys who made the rules never spent 30 secs thinking about their own rules - but they love making rules.